# Looking for big-endian hardware running linux with GCC >= 4.9.2

Tags: c++, c++11, embedded, hardware, endianness

I'm developing a communication framework that supports data serialization between machines of different byte order, which is very common in the automotive industry where small controllers are old school big-endian.

Now I need to test my code but I cannot find any hardware so far where I can just slam a ready made linux on it like with the raspberry pi.

Anybody have an idea?

The thing is I need at least GCC 4.9.2 for C++11 support, so all the ancient stuff is not gonna work.

Also it shouldn't cost more than a couple hundred bucks.

I tried QEMU before but it would just puke random error messages and it feels like nobody has ever tested that big-endian stuff.

I need something that I can just order, flash some SD card, boot it up, install gcc, compile my stuff and test it.

Comment: Anything with PowerPC on it? I guess the old servers could be had for a couple of bucks, not sure about what OS you can run on them nowadays

Comment: Debian 8 seems to have a powerpc port, that could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the debian 8 powerpc image ( https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/debian-installer/ ), try it in qemu:

*qemu-system-ppc -cdrom debian-8.11.0-powerpc-netinst.iso -boot d*

I get a normal debian installer that seems to be ready to install the thing.

Comment: Gives me: qemu-system-ppc: could not load PowerPC bios 'openbios-ppc'

Comment: @HugoMaxwell: and do you have the openbios-ppc package installed?

Comment: I'll be damned, it's installing as we speak. (ie. no I was missing that package, I did some googling on the error but nobody mentioned there was a package for it...)